# Spring boot application freezes after running for multiple days

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot app which I use to run some Controllers and a Scheduled task.  I start the app from the command line (I'm on windows) and it runs there for a couple of days, and then stops responding.  There are no errors, the output to the console just stops.  I have to hit CTRL+C to stop the app and restart it to start getting responses from it again.

The command line is stuck on the last line of output from the program.  The computer is a desktop, does not sleep or hibernate.  It's as if Spring Boot stopped accepting requests and stopped the Scheduled task.

Any help debugging this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A thread dump taken when the app is frozen should help to figure out what's going on

Comment: I had a similar problem in the past, try to serve the application as a Windows Service, with something like Java Service Wrapper.

Comment: please update if you have found a solution. I am facing a similar problem.